# Does java.lang.System.arraycopy() use a shallow copy?

Tags: java, arrays

[`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) is a shallow copy method.

For an array of a primitive type, it will copy the values from one array to another:

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,2};
int[] b = new int[2];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, 2);
```

`b` will be {1,2} now. Changes in `a` will not affect `b`.

For an array of a non-primitive type, it will copy the references of the object from one array to the other:

```
MyObject[] a = new MyObject[] { new MyObject(1), new MyObject(2)};
MyObject[] b = new MyObject[2];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, 2);
```

`b` will contain a reference of  `new MyObject(1)`, `new MyObject(2)` now. But, if there are any changes to `new MyObject(1)` in `a`,  it will affect `b` as well.

Are the above statements correct or not?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this so far? Have you tried writing some sample code?

Comment: Why not open up an IDE and find out?

Comment: So no sample code -1, not IDE -1? if you are a professor you will be out next semester. Sometimes I need a quick answer. Did you ask your co-worker some questions before you actually tried them before? If never, you are TOOOOOOOO smart. If you are a such smart guy, you need to be patient to other ordinary people. please ignore my any further questions later because most of time i may just ask without any sample and IDE things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***Above statements are correct or not?***

Yes, you are correct.

`System.arraycopy` **always does a shallow copy**, no matter if the array contains references or primitives such as `int`s or `doubles`s.

Changes in array `a` will never affect array `b` (unless `a == b` of course).

> ***But if any changes of new MyObject(1) in `a`, it will affect `b` as well.***

Depends on what you mean. To be picky, a change to the `new MyObject(1)` will neither affect `a` nor `b` (since they only contain *references* to the object, and *the reference* doesn't change). The change will be visible from both `a` and `b` though, no matter which reference you use to change the object.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct as long as you're specifically modifying properties and calling methods on your objects.

If you change where the reference points, for example with `a[0] = new MyObject(1)`, then even though the objects were created with the same initialization data, they will now point to different instances of the object and a change to one instance will not be seen in the other reference (in array `b`).